# Unable to run compiled scala project wither with scala or java "classNotFoundException: scala.xml.XML"

Tags: scala, build, compilation, jvm, scala-xml

I created a project with `sbt new scala/scala3.g8`

This is my modified build.sbt

```
val scala3Version = "3.2.1"

lazy val root = project
.in(file("."))
.settings(
  name := "bloomberg-clone",
  version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",

  scalaVersion := scala3Version,

  libraryDependencies += "org.scala-lang.modules" %% "scala-xml" % "2.1.0"
)
```

I've scala 3.2.1 and java 17 installed in my machine. My project structure is the following

```
bloomberg-clone % ls
README.md       build.sbt       project         src             target

src / main / scala / Main.scala
```

Main.scala has the following imports and @main method:

```
import scala.io.Source
import java.io.*
import scala.xml.{Elem, Node, Text, XML}
import scala.xml.transform.{RewriteRule, RuleTransformer}

@main def Main(inputFilePath: String, outputFilePath: String, numCopies: Int): Unit = 
{
val xmlList = loadXml(inputFilePath)
xmlList.flatMap { (node,fileName) =>
for (i <- 1 to numCopies) yield {
  val modifiedNode = transformXml(node)
  val modifiedOutputFilePath = createModifiedOutputFilePath(fileName,outputFilePath, i)
  writeXml(modifiedNode, modifiedOutputFilePath)
}
}
}
```

When I run the code from IntellJ, it works. When I compile using `sbt compile` and `sbt package`, and run the resulting jar as `scala out.jar a b 3` I get an error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: scala.xml.XML$`. If I run it with `java -jar out.jar a b 3`, I get `Error: Unable to initialize main class Main Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: scala/util/CommandLineParser$ParseError`.

Why is scala-xml not being packaged ?

Comment: The JAR produced by `package` does not contain the **scala-xml** classes, not even the **scala-library** classes. When you run it using `scala` that adds the **scala-library** in the CLASSPATH thus it only fails due the **scala-xml**, when you run it with `java` you don't even have that in scope thus it fails even sooner. - One easy way to solve this issue is using **sbt-assembly** to create a fat JAR that contains everything and can be run using `java -jar`, a more robust solution may be using **sbt-native-packager** and produce the right artifact for your target platform.

Comment: That explains many things... haha thanks. I'll learn a bit more of sbt to add sbt-native-packager and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Luis Miguel Mejía Suárez in the comments, the jar doesn't contain the scala-xml classes.
Assing sbt-assembly (project/plugins.sbt, create the file if it doesn't exist yet) `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "2.1.0")`

And modifying the build.sbt

```
lazy val app = (project in file("."))
.settings(
assembly / mainClass := Some("Main"),
// other settings
)
```

When running `sbt assembly` the jar under `target/scala-3.2.1/` contains all the dependencies (size is 7,9MB I guess this needs to be taken into account for larger applications)